# C# Where to put general methods?

Tags: c#, methods

In my application I have a method to check a variable is a number or not. This method is called more than once in my code. The method is called from the codebehind pages. Like this method I have more methods which i cannot place within a single class (like Staff). Where should I put this kind of methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a utility class file.

Comment: Yep.  I would definitely put those in a static class.

Comment: Further, I usually do this in a class without a namespace

Comment: @annakata The problem with not putting a name space is later on you get a lot of "Common" logic which then gets a bit messy.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 3.0, I would probably make this an extension method on the string class.  I would  group all of my string extensions into a single static class to improve readability.

```
 public static class StringExtensions
 {
      public static bool IsNumeric( this string source )
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( source ))
          { 
               return false;
          }
          ...
      }

      public static bool IsMoney( this string source )
      {
          ...
      }

      ...
 }
```

Usage:

```
 if (amountLabel.Text.IsNumeric())
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to write an extension method for Request.Querystring["value"] ?

Comment: Since the Item property of a NameValueCollection is a string, this extension method should work on it.  If you wanted to have something like Request.QueryString.IsNumeric("value"), then you'd need to make "this" of type NameValueCollection and rewrite the method accordingly.

Comment: @martijn: `TypeOf(Querystring["value"])==System.String` isn't it? so `MyStringExtensionsClass.ExtensionMethodName( this System.String theString, ... ) { ... }` would likely suffice

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your referring to a String variable.  If that's the case I would suggest one of two things

1. If you're using PRE .NET 3.0 you could put it in a StringHelper class like so:

   ```
   public static class StringHelper
   {
     public static bool StringIsNumber(String value)
     {
       //do your test here
     }
   }
   ```
2. If you're using POST .NET 3.0 you could refactor them as extension methods and do something like this

   ```
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       public bool IsNumber(this String value)
       {
       //do your test here
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Like the idea of an extension method

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be able to use the built-in functions `int.TryParse(string, out int)` or `double.TryParse(string, out double)` which both return a bool, but in any case go for ck's suggestion.